# Displaying a table using Blockbase

Tags: 8, blocks

In Drupal 8 within a custom block how do you display a render array?

I can easily display HTML markup with `#markup`, but I am not sure how to instead display a render array.

```
namespace Drupal\hello_world\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'Hello' Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "hello_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Hello block"),
 * )
 */
    class HelloBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
   public function build() {
return array(
  '#markup' => $this->t('Hello, World!'),
);
   }

 }
```

I'm trying to instead display a table render element such as the following, but can't seem to figure out how to add it to the block.

I've tried `hook_block_view_alter()`, like I would with `$form['build']`, with no success.

I've tried including it in the blocks build function (where #markup is in the sample code above).

I feel like I'm missing something super easy.

I'm trying to basically render something like this to no avail.

```
$build['table'] = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#caption' => $this->t('Our favorite colors.'),
  '#header' => [$this->t('Name'), $this->t('Favorite color')],
  '#rows' => [
    [$this->t('Amber'), $this->t('teal')],
    [$this->t('Addi'), $this->t('green')],
    [$this->t('Blake'), $this->t('#063')],
    [$this->t('Enid'), $this->t('indigo')],
    [$this->t('Joe'), $this->t('green')],
  ],
];
```

If you need any additional information please let me know.

Comment: You are already returning a render array. For a table, there is nothing different from what you already show in the other code snippet.

Comment: Did you try to return the build array `return $build;`? Don't see it in your second code example. Basically there is no difference between both examples, the array with #markup you return in the first example is a render array as well.